# sign out in MVC 4 using microsoft azure active directory

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

Hi i'm unable to sign out in my MVC 4 application.
I'm using Microsoft Azure Active Directory.
Using ACS 2.0.

I tried these examples but these are not clear.
can someone help me y sharing the code.
Im new to MVC4 and azure.

i'm really having hard time in understanding.
can someone help me?

Comment: which examples have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following links.

Developing Multi-Tenant Web Applications with Windows Azure AD
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151789.aspx

Adding Sign-On to Your Web Application Using Windows Azure AD
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151790.aspx